# meaning of a word in a particular context

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does *resolve* mean in the following sentence?

In spite of her **resolve**, her lips responded to his silent quest.

Comment: Hi, rahul. For this question to be suitable for this site, you should indicate what research you have attempted on your own (e.g. what did you find in the dictionary?) Also, please visit the help center for guidance on how to use this site. There is also a sister site ([ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)) for basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of her [determination](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Resolve), ( not to respond)...

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's not even a question of context--this is the primary nominal meaning of the word.